# JTextField Validation with integers

Tags: java, swing, int, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I am trying to validate integer values from a `JTextField`. I want to make sure the user only enters integer values between a set range. I tried working with a `JFormattedTextField` but so far no luck.

Comment: 1) Consider using a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) instead. 2) *".. so far no luck"*  Programming is not about 'luck'.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) of your attempt.

Comment: 1)Thanks for the reply..2)so far no luck is an expression meaning what I have been trying hasn't been working thus the reason for my question.

Comment: *"no luck is an expression"*  I'm aware of that.  IMO it should never be used in computing problems, save it for when you're at the dog track.  But get beyond that and move on to the important part of that comment - post an MCVE!

Comment: No sense in arguing your opinion since that is what it is. I am still working on my code so at the moment don't have something that makes sense for people to review and give input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good option is to use an `InputVerifier` - your text field will not yield focus unless the input conditions are met. A `JFormattedTextField` won't do here since your restriction is not solely format, but also mathematical.

```
public class NumRange extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new NumRange();
    }

    NumRange() {

        final int MIN = 0;
        final int MAX = 100;

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setInputVerifier(new InputVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
                String text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
                int num;
                try {
                    num = Integer.parseInt(text);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (num <= MAX && num >= MIN)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(textField);
        getContentPane().add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Try to switch focus to the bottom text field after entering various inputs to the top one.

Comment: Awesome thank you I did eventually find another way but this is also a good idea. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @JustyneTesterman Then you should post your solution and accept it (afterwards).